# How to safely manipulate MATLAB anonymous functions in string form

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, complex-numbers

I have an anonymous function that I would like to manipulate in string form then use with fsolve.
When I do this the references in the anonymous function to constants are lost and fsolve fails.

The problem is easily illustrated.

The following works:

```
A=3;
myfun=@(x)sin(A*x);
x = fsolve(@(x)myfun(x),[1 4],optimoptions('fsolve','Display','off'))
```

The following throws an error as explained [here](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
A=3;
myfun=@(x)sin(A*x);
mystring=func2str(myfun);
%string operations would go here such as strrep(mystring,'A','A^2') or whatever
myfun2=str2func(mystring);
x = fsolve(@(x)myfun2(x),[1 4],optimoptions('fsolve','Display','off'))
```

Is there some way I CAN safely manipulate an anonymous function while retaining references to constant parameters?

more info

Specifically I'm writing a simple wrapper to allow fsolve to accept imaginary numbers for simple cases. The following illustrates a working example *without* a constant parameter:

```
myeqn=@(x)0.5*x^2-5*x+14.5;
cX0=1+1*1i;
f1=strrep(func2str(myeqn),'@(x)','');
f2=strrep((f1),'x','(x(1)+(x(2))*1i)');
f3=strcat('@(x)[real(',f2,'); imag(',f2,')]');
fc=str2func(f3);
opts=optimoptions('fsolve','Display','off');
result=arrayfun(@(cinput)[1 1i]*(real(fsolve(fc,[real(cinput);imag(cinput)],opts))),cX0)
```

As in the failed example above if I include a parameter in my wrapper the process fails with the same error as above.

Comment: Do you have access to the symbolic math toolbox? It would be a much better tool to solve this.

Comment: The symbolic math toolbox is not relevent in cases where the anonymous function contains a numerical solution to problems which do not have a closed form solution.

Comment: I was not planning to use the symbolic solver, but the symbolic toolbox (especially `subs`) can be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally suggested to use the symbolic math toolbox, but reading your question again I realized it's just a simple substitution of input parameters. You can achieve this using function handles without any string processing.

```
myeqn=@(x)0.5*x^2-5*x+14.5;
cX0=1+1*1i;
wrapper=@(x,f)([real(f(x(1)+x(2)*i)),imag(f(x(1)+x(2)*i))])
opts=optimoptions('fsolve','Display','off');
result=arrayfun(@(cinput)[1 1i]*(real(fsolve(@(x)wrapper(x,myeqn),[real(cinput);imag(cinput)],opts))),cX0)
```

Comment: Nice. Also worth mentioning that if you want to retrieve the parameters from inside an anonymous function (or any function, actually) you can use the `functions` er... function.

Comment: Wow so simple! very nice.

Comment: I guess the moral of the story for me is - Dont use string operators to modify anonymous functions -> use anonymous functions to modify anonymous functions.

Comment: An important caveat for these manipulations is to be very aware of the scope of each anonymous function. ie in my case I needed to make sure I passed any additional parameters through the wrapper else they lost scope. ie wrapper=@(x,f,A)([real(f(x(1)+x(2)*i),A),imag(f(x(1)+x(2)*i),A)]) for example.

Answer (score -2):

As much as I hate to suggest using the `eval` function, you could do:

```
myfun2 = eval(mystring);
```

Using `eval` is kinda frowned upon because it makes code hard to analyze (since arbitrary nastiness could be going on in that string), but don't let other people's coding style stop you from doing what works :)

In your longer example, this would correspond to changing the line:

```
fc=str2func(f3);
```

to:

```
fc=eval(f3);
```

Again, the use of `eval` is strongly discouraged, so you should consider alternatives to this type of string manipulation of function definitions.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I was responding to the poster's first example (which defined `mystring` and tried to use `myfun2 = str2func(mystring)`) and assumed that he/she would be able to extrapolate the second example. I will edit my answer to explicitly address the second example.